# Linear map proof and $_{kan}[f]_{kan}$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I proove that $f:R^2\to R^2$, $f((x,y)^T)=(2x+y,x-2y)^T$ is linear map?
And what is its matrix $_{kan}[f]_{kan}$ for canonic basis $R^2$ then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is linear since $\forall(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2,f(x,y)=(ax+by,cx+dy)$, where $(a,b,c,d)=(2,1,1,-2)$

The images of the canonical vectors $C=\{e_1,e_2\}$ are
$$f(e_1)=f(1,0)=(2,1)$$
$$f(e_2)=f(0,1)=(1,-2).$$
The representative matrix will be $\mathcal M_c^c(f)=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$ and this also shows that $\text{dim}(Im(f))=2$, since the vectors that span the image of $f$ are linearly independent.